# Update a component from another component in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have 2 components. header and login.

In header

```
<a v-if="isLoggedIn" href="/#/insurance">
 <img src="@/assets/images/user.svg" class="profile_img">
 </a>
 <a v-else href="/#/login">
 <img src="@/assets/images/login.svg" class="profile_img">
 </a>
```

I want to toggle `isLoggedIn` `true` and `false` at `header` while a method is called at `login`

I have tried putting this at login

```
var userState = new Vue();
 userState.$emit('userState', true)
```

And this on header

```
updated(){
    userState.$on('userState', function(state) {
      this.isLoggedIn = state
    })
```

But it is not working. Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: If you need two unrelated components to talk, use a common parent component (app.vue, or a layout component) with props/emits or a vuex store. Using Vue as an EventBus (like you're trying with var userState is deprecated when you want to upgrade to Vue3.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is to use Vuex (which is a state management module). I won't cover Vuex in my answer. I only recommend it. It's robust and you'll end up needing it sooner than you think. Using `Vue.observable` (presented below) is only useful in simple cases. When you start needing `async` behavior it's probably time to start using Vuex.

---

Here's the simpler solution: `Vue.observable()`:

Declare a `Vue.observable()` containing whatever you want to share between the two components. Place it in a file and export it: E.g:

```
export default Vue.observable({
  isLoggedIn: false
})
```

In any component you want to read or write to that state object, import it:

```
import userState from '../path/to/userState.js'
```

If you only want to read from it, use it as a simple computed:

```
computed: {
  isLoggedIn() { return userState.isLoggedIn }
}
```

If you also want to write to it, use it as a setter + getter computed:

```
computed: {
  isLoggedIn: {
    get() { return userState.isLoggedIn; } 
    set(value) { userState.isLoggedIn = value; }
  }
}
```

That's it, really. Working example:

```js
const userState = Vue.observable({
  isLoggedIn: false
});

Vue.component('header-component', {
  template: `
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isLoggedIn">
  Logged in
</label>
  `,
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn: {
      get() {
        return userState.isLoggedIn
      },
      set(value) {
        userState.isLoggedIn = value
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('footer-component', {
  template: `<pre v-text="{ isLoggedIn }"></pre>`,
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      return userState.isLoggedIn
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#app>* {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#app main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#app pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<div id="app">
  <header-component></header-component>
  <main>main content here...</main>
  <footer-component></footer-component>
</div>
```

---

Note: `Vue.observable()` was introduced in Vue `2.6`.
If you want this functionality on a prior version, you can use a Vue instance instead of the observable.
Using a full-blown Vue instance instead of a `Vue.observable` is also useful when you want access to everything a Vue instance has to offer: watchers, computed, methods - which could be async, etc...

```
const userState = new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    isLoggedIn: false
  })
});
```

See it working (in `2.5`):

```js
const userState = new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    isLoggedIn: false
  })
});

Vue.component('header-component', {
  template: `
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isLoggedIn">
  Logged in
</label>
  `,
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn: {
      get() {
        return userState.isLoggedIn
      },
      set(value) {
        userState.isLoggedIn = value
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('footer-component', {
  template: `<pre v-text="{ isLoggedIn }"></pre>`,
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      return userState.isLoggedIn
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#app>* {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#app main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


#app pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17"></script>
<div id="app">
  <header-component></header-component>
  <main>main content here...</main>
  <footer-component></footer-component>
</div>
```